# boost::transform_iterator doesn't work with std::bind( &Pair::first, _1 )?

Tags: c++, boost, c++11

Traditional task of iterating trough key set of `std::map` led me to another mess which seems not to be disscused here yet.

In short, this code does not compile (C++11 is heavily used):

```
typedef std::pair<int, int> Pair;
vector<Pair> v {Pair(1,2), Pair(2,3)};
using namespace std::placeholders;
auto choose_first = std::bind(&Pair::first, _1);
boost::make_transform_iterator(v.begin(), choose_first);
```

Error message is as follows.

```
no type named 'result_type' in 'struct std::_Bind<std::_Mem_fn<int std::pair<int, int>::*>(std::_Placeholder<1>)>'
```

At the same time, changing `std::bind` to `boost::bind` fixes the problem. But there is a code convention in my project that we use `std::bind` only.

Any suggestions what to do with this? (Should I write bugreport to the Boost team?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are better ways to iterate over the keys of a `std::map` (or any container whose `value_type` is `pair<T,U>`), namely [Boost.Range](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/libs/range/doc/html/index.html)'s [`map_keys`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/libs/range/doc/html/range/reference/adaptors/reference/map_keys.html) adaptor (there's also a [`map_values`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/libs/range/doc/html/range/reference/adaptors/reference/map_values.html) one):

```
#include <boost/range/adaptor/map.hpp>
#include <utility>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

int main(){
  typedef std::pair<int, int> Pair;
  std::vector<Pair> v {Pair(1,2), Pair(2,3)};
  for(auto& first : v | boost::adaptors::map_keys){
    std::cout << first << " ";
  }
}
```

But back to your problem: All Boost libraries use the [Boost.Utility function `result_of`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/libs/utility/utility.htm#result_of), which won't fall back to `std::result_of` for whatever reason, and also won't use `decltype` if it's available without you telling it to. You do so by putting `#define BOOST_RESULT_OF_USE_DECLTYPE` before the first Boost include.

That, however, still didn't make your code compile with Clang 3.1 SVN + libc++. Here's the code I used:

```
#define BOOST_RESULT_OF_USE_DECLTYPE
#include <boost/iterator/transform_iterator.hpp>
#include <utility>
#include <vector>
#include <functional>

int main(){
  typedef std::pair<int, int> Pair;
  std::vector<Pair> v {Pair(1,2), Pair(2,3)};
  using namespace std::placeholders;
  auto choose_first = std::bind(&Pair::first, _1);
  boost::make_transform_iterator(v.begin(), choose_first);
}
```

Compiled with:

```
clang++ -std=c++0x -stdlib=libc++ -Wall -pedantic -Ipath/to/boost -Wno-mismatched-tags t.cpp
```

GCC 4.7 seems to accept this just fine, so I guess it's a bug in libc++.

Comment: As for map_keys: actually at the end I use some generic function which accepts an object which satisfy the STL container requirements (begin(), end()). So after making transform iterators, I pack them into boost::iterator_range and feed it to my function. I can't figure out, how to do it quicker. BOOST_RESULT_OF_USE_DECLTYPE doesn't help for some reasons in Boost 1.46, GCC 4.6.1. Maybe I'm doing something wrong…

Comment: @Artem: All ranges returned by Boost.Range adaptors have `begin()` and `end()` members, else they wouldn't work with range-for as I've shown. :) So just do `your_generic_func(v | map_keys)`.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you need to define BOOST_RESULT_OF_USE_DECLTYPE before including the boost library to actually use the C++11 method to get the result type, instead of relying on the legacy `result_type` member. This compiles fine on g++ 4.6 and 4.8:

```
#define BOOST_RESULT_OF_USE_DECLTYPE
// ^

#include <vector>
#include <boost/iterator/transform_iterator.hpp>
#include <functional>

int main()
{

typedef std::pair<int, int> Pair;
std::vector<Pair> v {Pair(1,2), Pair(2,3)};
using namespace std::placeholders;
auto choose_first = std::bind(&Pair::first, _1);
boost::make_transform_iterator(v.begin(), choose_first);

}
```

See the discussion thread http://lists.boost.org/boost-users/2012/01/72856.php to know why it is not enabled by default.

---

You could also workaround by using `std::mem_fn` instead of `std::bind`,

```
auto choose_first = std::mem_fn(&Pair::first);
```

which does define those legacy type members (§20.8.10/2). Since `std::mem_fn` is still part of the standard library I believe there's no problem using it in your team… ?

---

As a last resort, you could always use the C++03 way to declare a function object (of course we knew `std::unary_function` is deprecated):

```
template <typename T>
struct FirstChooser :
        public std::unary_function<const T&, typename T::first_type>
{
    typename T::first_type operator()(const T& input) const
    {
        return input.first;
    }
};

...

FirstChooser<Pair> choose_first;
```

Comment: I also see this requirement for std::mem_fn in Standard but GCC 4.6.1 still says: no type named 'result_type' in 'struct std::_Mem_fn<int std::pair<int, int>::*>'. As for BOOST_RESULT_OF_USE_DECLTYPE: it doesn't change anything as well with Boost version 1.46. Is it mandatory to use more recent version of Boost?

Comment: @ArtemPelenitsyn did you define it _before any other include_?

Comment: @ArtemPelenitsyn: `std::mem_fn` works in g++ 4.6.3. See update for the last-resort C++03 method. Not sure about Boost 1.46, as I am using 1.49 (any reason to stick with an old version?).

Comment: `std::mem_fn` is new and C++11 only. Not to be mistaken with `std::mem_fun` (and others), which is C++03 and deprecated for C++11.